# Accessing private variables using assembly

Tags: solidity, oracles, assembly, state-variable, private

I would like program an oracle service which I would like to charge a fee for. Therefore, I would store the data of interest as a private variable in my oracle contract. This private variable should only be accessed via a function which requires a minimum value payed by the calling contract.

I wonder, is my private variable really protected against phishing by other contracts? More specifically, is it possible to read a private variable of a different contract by any means? Obviously, it does not work with the standard solidity code but is it possible using assembly?

Comment: MaketDAO is doing this now with their ETH-USD price feed oracle

Answer (score 1):

A Solidity contract is unable to read the state storage of another contract by any means, including assembly. However, this provides no assurance of confidentiality.

*All* data in all contracts is readable by all nodes. This is because knowledge of the contract states is crucial for evaluating transactions results. By extension, it is well-understood by everyone who can contribute to protocol/node development. So, not uncommon knowledge.

You could separate concerns into on-chain and off-chain components. For example, the on-chain component could take owners, accept fees and emit events, e.g. `LogNewOrder(contract address, variable to inspect, callback function, etc)`. An off-chain Observer would inspect the contract storage and report findings back to your contract or directly to the client's callback.

Such a process is asynchronous because it has to wait for the off-chain part to respond. There is no obvious way to make it synchronous because your on-chain component cannot inspect other contract states.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I totally get your point. However, I am not not satisfied with your answer in two ways: 1. Let's say I am famous for providing some data in the off-chain world. I proof my authenticity of being the person, able to control the oracle contract. Since my data is publicly available in the off-chain world anyway, it does not matter that if it was also publicly available on the blockchain. The question is if it was possible to built a business model in which I sell my data on-chain using smart contracts. Meaning, is there no workaround for other contracts to steal my data?

Comment: 2. Could you explain me, please, how a contract can access a different contract's function? Do you have a good reference? I would like to understand your point, that "A Solidity contract is unable to read the state storage of another contract by any means, including assembly." Unfortunately, I am not familiar enough to understand the fundamentals of solidity/EVM. For me it seems that it is possible to jump to any place in storage since I could access a contract's function via a simple code like
`ContractA a = ContractA(addressA)`. Is this not copying variables but only functions?

Comment: The question was about "private" variables. I don't think they do what you want them to do. That does not imply it is not possible to design something closer to the point. It is probably best to ask a separate question about the best way to accomplish a defined set of goals and constraints. The answer has nothing to do with private variables and probably has nothing to do with assembly.

Answer (score 0):

No, smart contract may read only its owner storage, and not the storage of other smart contracts.  Though, off-chain applications may read storage or any contract.

Comment: But it is possible that a contract read another contracts function. Moreover, using delegate call it seems that the contract is able to access any code written in a different contract. I wonder, what prevents the attacking contract to overflow a certain storage area in my contract to access the private variable? Is there a criteria in the EVM which prevents to go to a certain storage area? Maybe I am just too naive and do not understand the working principle in depth. However, given the possibilities, I do not see a reason (yet) why this should not work.